# because it does not list the n in lowercase

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
[string]$dnisList = @"

22222222n
11111111j

"@

[string]$dnis = $dnisList.split('`n').trim().ToUpper() | Select-String  "(\d{8})([A-Z])" -AllMatches | ForEach {$_.Matches.value}

$dnis

output:
11111111j

output expected without modifying the list:
22222222n
11111111j
```

because it is not taking the first string, is it because it makes a line break with the n? How could I do it so that it would take it without modifying the list?

Comment: On my side,  the script is running correctly. This is the output I get: `22222222N 11111111J`. It is correct as you use `ToUpper`.

Comment: in powershell ise not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using single quotes,

```
 .Split('`n')
```

is being read as "split on back-tick OR 'n'" --- so your the 'n' in `22222222n` is being "eaten" by your `.Split()`:

```
PS > [string]$dnisList = @"
>>
>> 22222222n
>> 11111111j
>>
>> "@
>>
>> $dnisList.split('`n')

22222222

11111111j

PS >
```

and without the trailing letter, the first string never matches your regex in `Select-String`. Notice above that the `<NewLine>` was still present (as the first character in the second string) --- but that wasn't apparent because it was "eaten" by `.Trim()`:

```
PS > $dnisList.split('`n').Trim()
22222222
11111111j
PS >
```

Double-quotes are needed for back-tick escape seequences:

```
PS > $dnisList.split("`n").trim().ToUpper()

22222222N
11111111J

PS >
```

and then:

```
PS > $dnisList.split("`n").trim().ToUpper().ToUpper() | Select-String  "(\d{8})([A-Z])" -AllMatches | ForEach {$_.Matches.value}
22222222N
11111111J
PS >
```

Comment: Is this a difference between PowerShell and Windows PowerShell? Because in PowerShell (7.2.6) it seems to work with single quotes too.

Comment: If it's working for you with single quotes, it must be. I use Windows PowerShell (5.1), where back-tick+character is not interpreted.

Comment: OK, you finally gave me a reason to open 7.1. And there, you're right, it's read as a newline even with single quotes. But, interestingly, 'Line1`nLine2' still displays as a single line. So this probably has more to do with changes to the Split() method in the newer version of .net that underlies 7.1.